# How to make nested request call in gatling scala

Tags: scala, stress-testing, gatling

I was able to call nested request at 2 levels but at third level it does not execute, so is am  I doing it correct or not, if not what is correct way to execute nested request on basis of response

Here is my code what I have used

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import java.net.{URLDecoder, URLEncoder}
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class NestedRequestResoponse extends Simulation {
val scn = scenario("NestedRequestResoponse ")
.exec(http("request_2")
            .post("https://myurl:443/autho/login/login.html""")
            .formParam("""userid""", """userName""")
            .formParam("""password""", """password""")
            .formParam("""target""", """""")
            .formParam("""smauthreason""", """""")
            .formParam("""smquerydata""", """""")
            .formParam("""smagentname""", """""")
            .formParam("""postpreservationdata""", """""")
            .formParam("""SMENC""", """""")
            .formParam("""SMLOCALE""", """""")
            .check(currentLocation.transform(s => {
                val locationRegex = """.*/autho/fed/(.*)/.*""".r
                val locationKey = locationRegex findFirstIn s
                URLDecoder.decode(locationKey.get.replace("somepath/to/replace", ""), "UTF-8")
              }).saveAs("redirectURL") )
            .resources(         
                http("request_3 ${redirectURL}")
                .get("https://go.to.this.url:443${redirectURL}")
                .check(currentLocation.transform(s => {
                    val locationRegexN = """.*/*/.*""".r
                    val locationKeyN = locationRegexN findFirstIn s
                    URLDecoder.decode(locationKeyN.get, "UTF-8")
                  }).saveAs("pingURL") )
                    .resources(
                        http("request_4  ${pingURL}").get("${pingURL}").check(status.is(200))
                    )
            ))
}
```

So here I'm unable to execute "request_4", please suggest me right way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

We support only one level of resources.

Comment: So how to make nested calls based on response on one request?

Comment: resources block is for executing a concurrent batch of requests, like fetching page resources. Otherwise, just write exec(request1).exec(request2)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Stephane, I had tried that too, but the problem is if execute it in that way response gives 500 as status. I had tried with and without decoding URL of first request in both cases it does gives same response 500. Whereas its shows proper response in gatling recorder. So how does gatling recorder do its job to get correct output.